# How to get results for any of conditions that return true in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

The documents in my `Product` mongodb collection have the field `productName` and `productManufacturer`. Several manufacturers can make products with the same product name. I want to make a single query which receives an array of objects of the following format (just an example):

```
[
{
  productName: 'test1',
  productManufacturer: 'testManufacturer'
},
{
  productName: 'test2',
  productManufacturer: 'testManufacturer'
},
{
  productName: 'test3',
  productManufacturer: 'testManufacturer3'
}
]
```

and get all the relevant products.

I came up with this query so far:

```js
const products = await Product.find({
        $or: [
          $and: [{ 'productName':'test1' }, { 'productManufacturer':'testManufacturer' }],
          $and: [{ 'productName':'test2' }, { 'productManufacturer':'testManufacturer' }],
          $and: [{ 'productName':'test3' }, { 'productManufacturer':'testManufacturer3' }]
        ]
      })
```

According to mongodb [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/)

> $or uses short-circuit logic: the operation stops evaluation after
> encountering the first true expression.

So I'm not sure if all of my `$and` expressions will be evaluated. Is this correct way to make the query?

Comment: @Minsky I don't want to group products based on manufacturer. I just want to return an array of found products.

Comment: @turivishal The query actually worked in a couple of tests I made but I just wasn't sure whether it was by chance or this is actually a correct way. Because of the quote from docs I thought that maybe not all `$and`'s will be evaluated. Can you please confirm that all `$and` cases will be evaluated? If yes what does this quote mean? ($or uses short-circuit logic: the operation stops evaluation after encountering the first true expression)

Comment: You are referring [aggregation expression $or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) operator but you need to refer [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or) operator without expression documentation, both are little different, i am sure you have resolved your problem from this confusion.

Comment: @turivishal you're exactly right, I was looking at the wrong part of documentation